# Flattening and Counting 1-tuples

Tags: apache-pig

count_bool is compromised of single tuples that has the following output when I dump it:

```
(0)  
...  
(1)  
(0)  
...  
(0)
```

So if there are 100 - (0) and 20 - (1) I want the output to be:

```
(1, 20)
(0, 100)
```

And here is my attempt to flatten and count

```
count_by_xy = foreach count_by_subject generate flatten($0), COUNT($0);  
2013-07-09 00:05:43,590 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045:  
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.COUNT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'colName' is the name assigned to 1-tuple column:

```
count_group = group count_bool by colName;
```

'result' has what I am looking for:

```
result = foreach count_group generate $0, COUNT(count_bool);
```

`$0` refers the first column's value.

`flatten` is used to un-nest tuples, which is not needed here.